# Grails - createCriteria returns javassist instances instead of specific domain

Tags: grails, createcriteria

I'm using the following criteria to retrieve all `Person` objects that have certain roles granted (in the `PersonService`):

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
List findAllByRoles(authorities) {
    Person.createCriteria().list {
            personRoles {
                role {
                    'in'('authority', authorities)
                }
            }
            order('name', 'asc')
        }.unique(false)
}
```

I now have the problem that it returns a `List` with `Person__$$__javassist_67` objects rather than `Person` objects.

How could I alter the statement in order to retrieve `Person` objects?

EDIT:

I need this because I'm using the list I get here in connection with another list of `Person` objects. As I wanted to use `removeAll` on one of the two lists both need to contain objects of the same type what was not the case.

Comment: The better question is why are the proxy objects causing a problem for you?

Comment: Normally they wouldn't but I'm using the list I get here in connection with another list of `Person` objects. As I wanted to use `removeAll` on one of the two lists both need to contain objects of the same type what was not the case.

Comment: So the issue is the `equals` method. You can implement that method to check against any unique identifier and that process will work, proxy or not

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Enter it as an answer and you'll get the credit - I have updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `equals` method on `Person` to be able to identify if 2 instances are equal, which will work across proxy

Answer (score 0):

The `Person__$$__javassist_67` object is just a proxy for the `Person` class in this instance, caused most likely by lazy fetching.  I'm not sure why you are getting it in this situation.  I would attempt to explicitly set the `fetchMode`:

```
import org.hibernate.FetchMode
...
Person.createCriteria().list {
    fetchMode("personRoles", FetchMode.JOIN)
    fetchMode("role", FetchMode.JOIN)
    personRoles {
        role {
            'in'('authority', authorities)
        }
    }
    order('name', 'asc')
}.unique(false)
```

You may not need the second `fetchMode`.